# How can i save the order of lists i have changed using "drag" and "drop" from Angular cdk

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

I am trying to create three lists "to do", "doing", "done".
and drag and drop the items between them. When I refresh the the page the arrangement is also refreshed , how can I retain that state even after refreshing the page.

```js
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TaskService } from '../task.service';
import { Tasks } from '../tasks';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-displaytask',
  templateUrl: './displaytask.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./displaytask.component.css']
})
export class DisplaytaskComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: TaskService) { }
  toDo : string[] = [];
  doing : string[] = [];
  done :string[] = [];


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.displayAllProjects()
  }

  displayAllProjects()
  {
    this.service.getAllTasks().subscribe(data=>{
      data.forEach(t=>{
        this.toDo.push(t.project_name);
      })
    })
  }
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
   if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
     transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                     event.container.data,
                     event.previousIndex,
                      event.currentIndex);
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="drag-container">
            <div class="section-heading">To Do</div>
        
            <div cdkDropList #todolist="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="toDo" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doinglist,donelist]"
              class="item-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
              <div class="item-box" *ngFor="let item of toDo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="drag-container">
            <div class="section-heading">Doing</div>
        
            <div cdkDropList #doinglist="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="doing" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todolist,donelist]"
              class="item-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
              <div class="item-box" *ngFor="let item of doing" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="drag-container">
            <div class="section-heading">Done</div>
        
            <div cdkDropList #donelist="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="done" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todolist,doinglist]"
              class="item-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
              <div class="item-box" *ngFor="let item of done" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that all the items go back to the "todo" list, after refreshing that page. Please tell me how can I see the changes even after the page gets refreshed. Followed few tutorials but unable to fix it. Please tell me what is not correct in the above code.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFYxa.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpzG2.png

Comment: You can store it into local storage check the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage